# Are all allocations on UPF pareto optimal?

Tags: public-economics, public-goods

Are all allocations on UPF pareto optimal?
Was studying this in context of Public and Private goods. If someone can help.

Comment: Please specify all acronyms, such as UPF. Maybe also add a bit more detail, context, and your own thoughts/attempts to think through this question.

Comment: UPF stands for Utility Possibility Frontier. This was a question posed in my public economics exam for the unit -Public goods as 1 marker

Comment: There are different nonequivalent definitions of both Pareto optimality and the UPF. In the current form, the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a 2-consumer, 2-goods pure-exchange economy:
$<(u_A:\mathbb{R}^2_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R},(\omega^X_A,\omega^Y_A)), (u_B:\mathbb{R}^2_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, (\omega^X_B,\omega^Y_B))>$

Set of feasible allocations is
$\mathcal{F} = \{((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}^2_+|x_A+x_B=\omega_A^X+\omega_B^X \ \wedge \ y_A+y_B=\omega_A^Y+\omega_B^Y\}$

We can define utility possibility set as:

$\text{UPS} = \{(\mu_A,\mu_B)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\mu_A\leq u_A(x_A,y_A) \ \wedge \mu_B \leq u_B(x_B,y_B) \text{ for some } ((x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B))\in\mathcal{F}\}$

Utility Possibility Frontier is defined as
$\text{UPF} = \{(\mu_A,\mu_B)\in\mathbb{R}^2|(\mu_A,\mu_B) \text{ is the limit point of UPS and there exists no } (\mu_A',\mu_B')\in\text{UPS satisfying } \mu_A'>\mu_A, \mu_B'>\mu_B  \}$

Consider the exchange economy $u_A(x_A,y_A) = \max(x_A,y_A)$, $u_B(x_B,y_B) = \max(x_B,y_B)$. Total endowment of X and Y is $1$ unit each.

Set of Pareto efficient allocations in this economy consists of two allocations
$\{((1,0),(0,1)),((0,1),(1,0))\}$

Utility possibility set is:

$\text{UPS}=\{(\mu_A,\mu_B)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\max(\mu_A,\mu_B)\leq 1\}$

and utility possibility frontier is:

$\text{UPF}=\{(\mu_A,\mu_B)\in\mathbb{R}^2|\max(\mu_A,\mu_B)= 1\}$

Here is the picture:
[image]

Observe that the only utility pair in the above example that corresponds to Pareto efficient allocation(s) is $(\mu_A,\mu_B)=(1,1)$. If we consider $(\mu_A,\mu_B)=(1,0)$ on the frontier, this utility pair can be achieved by an inefficient allocation such as $((1,1),(0,0))$. This example demonstrates that a utility pair on the frontier may not always correspond to a Pareto-efficient allocation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It really helped.